# How To Read Failed Transaction Simulation Logs

Tags: solana-cli

If I run the following I get a simulation error

```
Updating GzG3Qic5vQcyNyrMdhKH7V1BS16BKJiCY3gkm7po5oGA
  Current freeze authority: DvE296LNkXnquYiQBhS6M9GXRHisx8TkCXt2e2XtkN7q
  New freeze authority: H1DjeTdZGQmFGiFy7nVC1JithR6jd3TTqP4HnQyQwsou
RPC response error -32002: Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 0: custom program error: 0x4 [5 log messages]
```

I'm not sure where to look to create the 5 log messages.

Comment: we are also having a ton of issues in delegated freeze auth and freeze auth, were you able to get anywhere on this?

Answer (score 1):

Set the envvar `RUSTLOG=solana_client=debug` before running the command

Comment: is there anything else I have to do? i entered `export RUSTLOG=solana_client=debug`, but the error still says ```Error: RPC response error -32002: Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 0: custom program error: 0x1774 [5 log messages]```

Comment: please update the question with the full series of commands you run and their output

Comment: this is not my question.. do you want me to make a duplicate one?

Comment: yes.  and don't threadjack in the future